# Word 2016 typing 'iDIN?' toggles caps-lock and changes capitalization

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, autocorrect

I'm writing a report in Word 2016 (Office 365 ProPlus, version 16.0.6741.2963) and every time I type the string 'iDIN?' it automatically gets converted to 'Idin?' and it toggles my caps-lock. At first i thought it only happened when I used it at the end of a sentence, but now it's doing it wherever, no matter the context. I have identified the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Caps-lock off**
I type 'iDIN?', it gets converted to 'Idin?' and my caps-lock is turned on

**Scenario 2: Caps-lock off**
I type 'Idin?', it does not get converted and my caps-lock remains off

**Scenario 3: Caps-lock on**
I type 'iDIN?', It gets converted to 'Idin?' and my caps-lock is turned off

**Scenario 4: Caps-lock on**
I type 'Idin?', It does not get converted and my caps-lock remains on

The text is converted as soon as I type the question mark. No other text (apart from the 'iDIN?' string) appears to be effected by this.

When I open a new document, this behavior does not happen until I start a new line with two slashes (//) and end the line with 'iDIN?'. I did this in my original document to include a `//TODO:` note, where the line ended with 'iDIN?'

Any help on figuring out what could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word  go to - File - Options - Proofing

In Autocorrect tab remove mark from "Correct accidental usage of cAPS LOCK key".

This is a general setting, if you'd prefer to keep it, then you can also create an autocorrect rule (at the bottom of the same form): Replace "idin?" to "iDIN?", this way just type it with lowercase letters and Word will automatically convert it to the right form.

Comment: Thanks, that did solve it. I'm curious as to why I could be typing an entire document without this happening, and it only starting after I start a new line beginning with // and ending in iDIN?.